# What "risk" implies in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, definition

Definition of risk according to Cambridge :—

*to do something although there is a chance of a bad result*

***He risked losing his house when his company went bankrupt.***

How I can adjust the definition grammatically in the sentence??

Comment: If you risk something important, i.e. "losing his house", you are in a danger to lose it. *The "-ing" noun (or gerund) is the direct object of the verb risk*.

Comment: @Graffito how I can use the definition in the sentence?

Comment: That exact definition doesn't *precisely* match your example context, where it's more like *He **was** [underwent the experience of being] **at risk of** losing his house...* - even though he might not have actively *done* anything to incur that risk (apart from being in the wrong place at the wrong time! :) Which is a perfectly natural use of the verb, but I can't find it defined exactly like that anywhere (including even the *full, subscription-only* OED).

Comment: ...so it's not exactly the same as *He risked losing his house by standing guarantor for his son's business loan* (a deliberate but risky act, with his house effectively being the "stake" in a "gamble").

Comment: The meaning of *risk* in your example is not the one you cite from *Cambridge*, but more like *face a non negligible chance of a bad result*.

Comment: He risked losing his house when his company went bankrupt means "He **was exposed to the chance of** losing his house when his company went bankrupt."

Comment: Please check your question forms: How **can I** use the definition in a sentence. This is a basic form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Risk" can be a verb or a noun.

Something, such as a course of action that has a potentially bad outcome, can be '*a risk*'. For example, "*buying a house without first inspecting it is **a** risk*".

"*To risk [something]*" can mean to carry out an action which could potentially result in the loss of that thing. It can also mean, as in your example, to *face a possibility*, whether deliberate or not. If you'd read more definitions in Cambridge, you would have come across this. "*to do something or to enter a situation where there is a possibility of being hurt or of a loss or defeat*".